# Host name verification in Spring Web Services

Tags: java, security, ssl, soapui, spring-ws

I'd like to inquire on the origins of the difference in host verification behavior I'm observing with Spring Web Services, 2.2.2.RELEASE (under Spring Boot 1.3.0.M4) on Java 1.7.

When configuring the WebServiceTemplate to use HttpComponentsMessageSender I end up with the error reading as follows:

```
I/O error: Certificate for <uswebservice.uat.hroffice.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.sbcsystems.com, sbcsystems.com]; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Certificate for <uswebservice.uat.hroffice.com> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.sbcsystems.com, sbcsystems.com]
```

When I reconfigure WebServiceTemplate to use *HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender* instead, the above error disappears and the call to verify the host name (as per [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1)) doesn't seem to occur vs. how it does in the above case (or at least I'm unable to trace it) although I could see that Spring's *HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender*'s connection (*sun.net.www.protocol.https.DelegateHttpsURLConnection:**https:// uswebservice.uat.hroffice.com/IWSUAT/customS**...*) is assigned a respective host name verifier in its *createConnection()* method
*(javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection$DefaultHostnameVerifier)*.

Whether the host name verification occurs or doesn't occur here in the successful case (I'm inclined to think that it still does, but would appreciate a hand in discovering **how it's been invoked**) what I'm questioning is where the *HttpComponentsMessageSender* (the erroneous case) obtains the certificate that makes verification fail.  I checked *cacerts* file that comes with Java installation (*\jdk1.7.0_76\jre\lib\security*) - it's not there.  The certificate present at the secure url (above) contains the correct Subject Alt Name:

```
Not Critical
DNS Name: *.uat.hroffice.com
DNS Name: uat.hroffice.com
```

whereas in the case that produces the error, the certificate seems to have the following values for the Subject Alt Name field which makes it fail trying to dereference the URI above as per the spec :

```
[8]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
  DNSName: *.sbcsystems.com
  DNSName: sbcsystems.com
]
```

The mysterious certificate in question is also visible in SoapUI (which is how I'm able to obtain in) however running the test in that tool doesn't produce an error - I'm assuming the host name verification is being somehow bypassed there (perhaps someone knows the details).

The certificates are two distinct ones as they have different expiration dates.

I also tried to disable host name verification via providing a noop implementation of *HostnameVerifier* but that seems to be a questionable approach to security so in a quest to abandon it I'm stumbled by the questions described above.

I appreciate in advance if someone could shed a bit more light at the symptoms I'm experiencing.

Here are the related Spring configurations:

```
@Bean
public KeyStore keyStore() throws Throwable {
    KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactory = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
    keyStoreFactory.setPassword(keyStorePassword);
    keyStoreFactory.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(keyStoreName));
    keyStoreFactory.setType("jks");
    keyStoreFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return keyStoreFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean 
public KeyManager[] keyManagers() throws Throwable{
    KeyManagersFactoryBean keyManagerFactory = new KeyManagersFactoryBean();
    keyManagerFactory.setKeyStore(keyStore());
    keyManagerFactory.setPassword(keyStorePassword);
    keyManagerFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return keyManagerFactory.getObject();
}

@Bean
public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender httpsUrlSender() throws Throwable {
    HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender sender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
    sender.setSslProtocol("TLS");
    sender.setKeyManagers(keyManagers());

    /*sender.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
            return true;
        }});*/
    return sender;
}




@Bean
public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Throwable {
    WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();
    webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller());
    webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller());
    webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri(defaultUri);
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageFactory(messageFactory());
    webServiceTemplate.setMessageSender(/*new HttpComponentsMessageSender()*/httpsUrlSender());
    return webServiceTemplate;
}
```

When analyzing the site at ssllabs.com it's reported to only work in browsers with SNI support, perhaps the fact that it's used from Java too has some effect on the above behavior (however Java 1.7 seem to have added the correct SNI behavior by default)?

[image]

Comment: yes, apparently, SNI isn't sent from client. The server at the IP hosts multiple domains; without SNI, it sends back a default/random cert. I am very surprised that this is still a problem in famous java libs like Spring and Apache HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks @bayou.io.  Well, not so much a problem - there are ways of dealing with it via additional configurations as I'm describing, but certainly not something well documented, hence my question.  Is there something that needs to be done to force SNI being sent by my app?  Would certainly welcome insights from Spring WS and Apache HttpClient communities.

Comment: Without SNI, the gateway could forward the connection to a wrong host. We definitely do not want to disable hostname verification.

Comment: Might it have anything to do with the following SNI issue on HttpClient: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-1119 and has this fix been incorporated into the version of Spring WS used by Spring Boot 1.3.0.M4?  Any additional configurations that need to be applied to enable proper SNI support in the Spring Boot app?